# Git Sourcetree Push / Upload Project Files Error

Tags: git, github

I wanted to upload my project files to my Git Repo via Sourcetree. But I encountered an error like this. How can I get rid of this problem?

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags origin main:main
Pushing to https://github.com/akncn57/Ball-Rolling
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (150/150), 1.6 MB | 426 KB/s, done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
remote: warning: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.sysroot.linux-x86_64@0.1.14-preview/data~/payload.tar.7z is 80.54 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB        
remote: error: Trace: ec453515c09cb09eb2104c165297d3720366c18c862fb9b854a0d1e0428172e1        
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.        
remote: error: File Library/PackageCache/com.unity.toolchain.win-x86_64-linux-x86_64@0.1.20-preview/data~/payload.tar.7z is 297.60 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 1):

The warning and error are pretty clear. The binaries you want to push are too large (GitHub issues a warning above 50MB and throws error above 100MB). In order to make it work, install Git LFS (Large File Storage). Other than installing & configuring it, the experience will be seamless. GitHub free will then accept files up to 2GB.
See details here: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github.